# Postgres - No actual UPDATE, has it side-effects?

Tags: performance, postgresql, query-performance

I have a table which holds about 50M rows. I want to execute a simple UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE the_table SET flag = true;
```

For 99% of these rows, the flag is already set to true. So only 1% of the rows must be changed.

My question is: is Postgres smart enough to know this? Or will Postgres change these 99% rows anyway, which will result in the typical processes such as WAL, auto-vacuum, re-indexing, synchronization to slaves, ... for the whole table, instead of just for these 1% rows.

In other words, is the following query a safer approach?

```
UPDATE the_table SET flag = true WHERE flag = false;
```

Comment: it will update as many rows as tell it to. In your case without `where` it will update all rows, so for sure go for the second statement

Comment: Obligatory use where clause, otherwise all rows will be affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres won't distinguish between the case where *flag=true* or *flag=false* (or *flag is null*, for that matter) when performing the update. However, the results of the two statements are not completely equivalent; or, at least, they're not in general.

There are two major side effects:

1. The first query (no where clause) will scan and process all the rows in the table. In the second case, and having appropriate indices, it might only go and process a few rows. The end result in terms of "what's on the table" (barring the effects of triggers) will be the same. The time taken to achieve this end result might be substantially different.
2. If the table (or view) has a [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/trigger-definition.html) that fires "ON UPDATE" and "FOR EVERY ROW" (see [`CREATE TRIGGER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html)), the trigger function will be called for every row on the table with your first query, and only for the rows `WHERE` the *where condition* is true on the second. Again two differences: (1) time and (2) the action of the trigger. If the trigger would, for instance, update a "lastmod" column, it would update it for every row in the first case [which is probably not what you want].

... and a possible third one:

3. In a sufficiently concurrent scenario: the first query will block all the rows in the table; or the statement might be blocked from updating some rows because another transaction is simultaneously them. So, either long wait times or deadlock. The higher the number of rows updated, the higher the likelihood of having some effects on contention... (or deadlocks, etc.)

The most usual way of updating is using a query with a `WHERE` clause. Some very special cases might recommend the first one (for instance, you *actually want* a "lastmod" column updated, even if the rest of the values in the row were not).

"By default" go for the query with a `WHERE`. Some databases (i.e.: MySQL and [safe update](http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2011/10/mysql-safe-update/)) might even not allow you to execute an UPDATE (or DELETE) without a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 4):

No, Postgres does not check if you are updating to the same value.

Every now and then this is discussed on the mailing list(s), but the consensus is that the check is too expensive and there is no point in making all users pay for something that only a few users (typically users of bad obfuscation layers - aka "ORM") need.

The second solution is the safe and best way of doing the update.

Comment: Obfuscation layers - aka "ORM" ;)

Comment: @klin: doesn't ORM stand for "Obfuscated Relational Model"? :)

Comment: I think so, especially when I see questions like *How can I write this query in my ORM?*